# Rewriting file and calling script recurrently

Tags: python, python-2.7, replace, terminal, file-writing

In my current project, I'm trying to receive a list of values (for now I'm ok with receiving them as a list of strings as that makes a part of the code easier), a name of a file, and iterate through the values to change the value on the file in order to submit many calls to the terminal at once. The problem I have right now is, I believe, that though I'm changing the values, the submitted files are not different from the initial file because I'm failing to realize that I'm not rewriting the file correctly.

**1st Part - Input**

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
if len(sys.argv) < 1:
    print "Specify the input"
    exit(1)
f = sys.argv[1]
list = ast.literal_eval(sys.argv[3])
```

**2nd Part - Rewriting**

```
while i < len(list):
  with open(f, 'r+') as file:
    programFile = file.read()

  for l in range(len(node)):
    if i==0:
        valuesDic.update({"initialValue":list[i]})
    else:
        valuesDic.update({list[i-1]:list[i]})

    multiValuesChange(programFile, valuesDic)

    out_file = open(f, "w")
    out_file.write(programFile)
    out_file.close()
    call(["qsub","-l","h=node10",f])
    i=i+1
```

**3rd Part - multiValuesChange**

```
def multiValuesChange(programFile, valuesDic):

    rc = re.compile('|'.join(map(re.escape, valuesDic)))
    def translate(match):
        return valuesDic[match.group(0)]
    return rc.sub(translate, programFile)
```

Thank you.

Comment: Post the code of the  multiValuesChange() function.

Comment: `out_file.write(s)`  <-- where are you getting this `s` variable from?

Comment: Sorry, I had a different version of the code and copied here from the wrong one. This s should be programFile.

Comment: Are you updating `i`? A better way would to be have another `for i in range(len(lzt))` instead of the while loop (and rename your variable to something not a keyword)

Comment: If you are talking about the list string, I changed the name to post here so that it would be obvious what it was without the rest of the code. Thanks for the heads-up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `programFile` is a string. Strings are immutable. If you want to update it you'll have to collect it back after being processed through the `multiValuesChange()` function, so do:

```
programFile = multiValuesChange(programFile, valuesDic)
```